# nl2br not clearing all new lines

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some strange issue with nl2br so I have the following code:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<?= nl2br($store["Stores"]["address"]) ?>"
});
```

the output when viewing the browser source is as shown in this image:

[image]

As you can see the `<br />` have been correctly introduced but for some reason the line still breaks which causes a javascript error.

The variables values is what has been posted from the text area input of the form

Comment: It could be because of the carriage return character (`\r`) which is not the same as `\n` and may be interpreted as a newline in JavaScript... that would be an odd case, though.

Comment: Directly inserting text into javascript is hazardous. At bare minimum, you could also be passing things through `json_encode()`, which is guaranteed to produce valid javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can see from the examples in the [documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), this seems to be intended behaviour. if you want to replace all newlines to get the string into one line, a simple regex should do it. this is how i would try (typed out of my head, this isn't tested):

```
<?= preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/','<br/>',$store["Stores"]["address"]) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour of [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br). If you want to remove the newlines in the string you'll have to use preg_replace.

```
<?= preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", "<br />", $input)
```

Answer (score 1):

nl2br does not remove newlines, it just inserts < br /> before them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: <>"<?= nl2br($store["Stores"]["address"]) ?>"</>.toString()
});
```